# How to hide Comment Box after Like something?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like

I just want to use the like button and not show any comment popup. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.fb_edge_widget_with_comment iframe { height: 20px !important; overflow: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it with a little but of css to hide the DOM element that Facebook adds.

```
.fb_edge_widget_with_comment span.fb_edge_comment_widget {
display: none !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have success with the above approach. What worked for me was to create a container element with the exact dimensions of the facebook like button and set `overflow="hidden"` to the container. This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: For the reference, mine is 73px wide and 21px in height.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#fb-container {
height: 20px !important;
width: 93px !important;
overflow: hidden !important;      
}
</style>

<div id="fb-container">
   <div id="fb-root">
       <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/youraddr" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false">
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this style to the style="overflow: hidden !important;" to the div like i have done below

```
<div class="fb-like pull-right" data-href="http://thegoldbook.in/demo/singlequestion.php?ques_no='.$ques_id.'" data-width="100" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true" style="overflow: hidden !important;"></div>
```